# Compression Assemblies for C#/.Net?

Tags: c#, compression, archiving

I know about SharpZipLib...but what else is out there? I'd like to make myself a file archiving utility that supports multiple compression formats. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really an answer, so I'll post it as a comment. Coming soon: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/28/working-with-zip-files-in-net.aspx

Answer (score 4):

QuickLZ claims to be the fastest in the world.

http://www.quicklz.com/

How about System.IO.Packaging?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There's the built-in [System.IO.Compression library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx) which supports GZip and Deflate. That's not a bad place to start as its documentation is better than most.

Answer (score 1):

LZMA SDK (7-Zip format) - one of the more efficient algorithms out there.

http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Answer (score 1):

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ <-- imho easier than sharpziplib

http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/ <-- wrapper around 7zip

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/zip-dotnet.asp <-- not free. bz2, gzip and .z